# java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery

Tags: android, exception, android-contacts, android-cursor

Hy everybody,

I have an error and i don't know what is wrong

Here is my error from log

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery (mSql = SELECT display_name, _id FROM view_data_restricted data WHERE (1) AND (data1 =? AND mimetype='vnd.android.cursor.item/group_membership' AND display_name like '%r%') ORDER BY display_name)
```

and here is my code

```
public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
filter = nome.getText().toString();

try{
tempCurs = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[]{ContactsContract.Groups._ID,ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE},
    ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME + " =? " + " AND " + ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE + " !=? ",
    new String[]{accountName,nomeGrupo},
    null
    );      
if(tempCurs.moveToFirst())
    do{
        cursorContactosGrupos = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership._ID},
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID + " =? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.DISPLAY_NAME + " like '%" + filter + "%'" ,
                new String[]{String.valueOf(tempCurs.getLong(0))},
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.DISPLAY_NAME
                );
         //Log.w(SocioEdit.class.getName(), "->" + cursorContactosGrupos.getString(cursorContactosGrupos.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            }while(tempCurs.moveToNext());
        }finally{
            if(cursorContactosGrupos != null && tempCurs != null && !cursorContactosGrupos.isClosed() && !tempCurs.isClosed()){
                cursorContactosGrupos.close();
                tempCurs.close();
            }   
        }
        return cursorContactosGrupos;
    }       
});
```

What I'm doing wrong?And how can fix?
Thanks for help

Comment: getContentResolver() return DB object right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is possibly because you are returning a `Cursor` that you have already closed in the `finally` block and you may be trying to use the returned value.

Change the `finally` block to the following:

```
finally{
    if(tempCurs != null && !tempCurs.isClosed()){
        tempCurs.close();
    }   
}
```

and remember to close the returned `Cursor` from the calling method.

Comment: Yes, Thats true but instead telling that you should find out where he is doing wrong in code.

Comment: A method that returns a closed Cursor without performing anything else is a useless method and that itself is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Try **removing** following lines of your code then check again,

```
finally{
            if(cursorContactosGrupos != null && tempCurs != null && !cursorContactosGrupos.isClosed() && !tempCurs.isClosed()){
                cursorContactosGrupos.close();
                tempCurs.close();
            }
```

**Add** this instead

```
finally{
                if(cursorContactosGrupos != null && tempCurs != null && !cursorContactosGrupos.isClosed() && !tempCurs.isClosed()){

                    tempCurs.close();
                }
```

Comment: You will be leaking a `Cursor` if you remove the lines. It is not correct.

Comment: Ten why the method which contains this line is returning cursor if you want to close cursor which will be no longer in use, you can have method with void as return type, i don't think my answer should be down voted for this, question itself is like this what to do? :)

Comment: I just use this two cursors in this function. I don't open in another side. I think that i can't remove this lines because the cursors need to be closed...

Comment: @Ricardo Then why are you closing both cursor inside finally block and returning closed cursor?

Comment: yeah. you're right. My mistake. If i return a closed cursor i don't have the results of the cursor

Comment: @Ricardo So if this is the mistake that you were doing and now its working with code change that i suggested, you can mark this answer as accepted one or may be Upvote along with it. :)

Comment: My objective is to filter my autocompletetextview with the contacts that I have in tha phone. And I  try to return a cursor with the contacts that I want. This is the best way to do this?adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
  @Override
 public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {     ......................

Comment: Yes this is the best way i guess, i couldn't think of anything better than this. :)

Comment: @Rinkalkumar, Your answer was downvoted because, instead of rectifying the problem, you were suggesting something that would complicate the issue. I have undid the downvote after your edit, although there are still some mistakes left. There was nothing wrong with the question and you can see that user1417430's answer seems to address the issue perfectly. And in the future, please do not attempt to hijack the answer of someone else.